# Битрикс и поиск процентов в наименовании элемента

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть в инфоблоке наименования элементов с процентами на конце, например ...±2%-А и ...±2%
Через CIBlockElement::GetList ищу элемент с наименованием ...±2% и из-за процента в конце наименования и встроенного фильтра "маска" по наименованию элементов выводит два экземпляра. Как побороть эту проблему и сделать точный поиск, используя процент в конце именно как часть имени?

Comment: Возможно экранирование процента это `%%` или `\%`.

Comment: Увы, не помогло.

Comment: Битрикс вроде бы делает сам экранировку для %. См. CIBlock::ForLIKE($val).

Comment: Используется ```"NAME"=>``` или ```"%NAME"=>```?